# PHP not reset page content after a page refresh

Tags: php

I'm creating a login website using PHP.

```php
$valid = true;
$sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result === false) {
    $valid = false;
}
if ($valid === false) {
    echo "Wrong username and password";
}
```

If I input the **wrong** username and password, I'll receive the **error line**. However, when I try to **refresh** the page, that **error line still remains**. How can I make it disappear?

Comment: PHP has defined `true` and `false` constants to be in place of your literal integer values. Also using the negation operator `!` will have mixed results when the return type itself is mixed. Instead use `!== false` to rule out `false` returns in your conditionals.

Comment: Your connection to the db could be in error `$conn`. Are you sure you are connected to the db?

Comment: Also regarding this "However, when I try to refresh the page, that error line still remains. How can I make it disappear?" .... any GET and POST vars will persists on a refresh of thats what you are choosing to happen. I suppose the problem is not solvable without more of your code to examine here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to check if **NOT** valid.

```
if ($valid != 1) {
    echo "Wrong username and password";
}
```

Comment: Ah yes. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
$valid = 1;
$sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result) {
    $valid = 0;
}
if ($valid) {
    echo "Wrong username and password";
}
```